# why date gets changed when i try to change formate?

Tags: iphone, ios

this is the code that i am using for changing date formate

```
      NSLog(@"newBirthDates%@",_newwBirthDates);
    NSDateFormatter *Form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [Form setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
    NSDate *date1 =[NSDate date];
    NSString *string =[Form stringFromDate:date1];
     NSLog(@"string%@",string);
    NSDate *todaydate =[Form dateFromString:string];
     NSLog(@"todaydate%@",todaydate);
```

this is what i get as output

```
     newBirthDates(
    "05/22",
    "07/11",
    "10/07",
    "02/20"
)
 newBirthDates(
    "05/22",
    "07/11",
    "10/07",
    "02/20"
)
 string03/18
 todaydate1970-03-17 18:30:00 +0000
```

now my question is why 3/18 become 03/17??  why one day get decreases

Comment: A tip: always save complete date in variable/database, and formate them only when showing in UI, in your particular case, this may be because you are not saving/getting year in the date string.

Comment: Added only one of the possible duplicates but the problem with checking whether date is correct using `NSLog` has been answered many times already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple - time zones.
Take a close look at what `NSLog` prints out
`1970-03-17 18:30:00` **`+0000`**

By default, a `NSDateFormatter` is set to your local timezone. That means, if your time zone is `+5:30` giving it a date "1970/18/3" results in `1970-03-18 00:00:00` **`+0530`**.
However, `NSLog` always prints dates in GMT (zero) time zone, adding/substracting the time zone difference (5 hours and 30 minutes).

Basically, there is nothing to fix, you just have to understand how `NSLog` works if you want to use it to check `NSDate` values.

Comment: wow wow who is this man? ha ha ha thank u but what is solution? we now know how nslog works but how to over come this problem? i add only single date in array which is of today and then in computer i set date to 03/17 11.59 pm and yes it wont go in if condition in code cus dates are not same obvious they wont be same now user is sleeping with app close and then its turns 12 am means 18th so why dont i get notification?

Comment: sorry man u i started to talk about some other things just neglect it

Answer (score 1):

Your Log is showing as per string value, eliminating all important timezone differences.

Log of `NSDate` shows you the time from GMT.

And both the values are correct.

> The sole primitive method of NSDate, timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate,
>   provides the basis for all the other methods in the NSDate interface.
>   This method returns a time value relative to an absolute reference
>   date—the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT.

You must read [NSDate Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

for getting correct date you can use this one,

```
 NSDateFormatter *Form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [Form setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
    [Form setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSDate *date1 =[NSDate date];
    NSString *string =[Form stringFromDate:date1];
    NSLog(@"string%@",string);
    NSDate *todaydate =[Form dateFromString:string];
    NSLog(@"todaydate%@",todaydate);
```

above code will give the correct date.

Answer (score 1):

The Main thing is **TimeZone** : `[Form setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];`

**This is the Correct Code :**

```
NSDateFormatter *Form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[Form setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[Form setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
NSDate *date =[NSDate date];
NSString *string =[Form stringFromDate:date];
NSDate *todaydate = [Form dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"todaydate %@",todaydate);
```